# BizTalk Deployment Framework missing Microsoft.BizTalk.Interop.SSOClient Version 9.0.1000.0

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-deployment

I'm having some problems deploying my current BizTalk Solution. I've just taken over the project and it seems that the Deployment Framework was working until now. Everything is set up up but when I run the deployment this error occurs:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\DeploymentFrameworkForBizTalk\5.0\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets(1727,5): error MSB4018: Unexpected Error on the UpdateSSOConfigItem-Task.
>
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The File or Assembly "Microsoft.BizTalk.Interop.SSOClient, Version=9.0.1000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" could not be found

Error occurs while running `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\DeploymentFrameworkForBizTalk\5.0\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets(1727,5)`

I guess its coming from the SSOFileReader.dll (which should be referencing the assembly?) and indeed, the assembly is missing in the GAC. But the QS and PROD server seem to be set up equally to DEV, they're missing the assembly too, but the deployment works.

I'm very new the all of this BizTalk stuff and haven't done anything with the Deployment Framework yet, would appreciate some help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing this problem too: 
My solution was to completely re-configure the deployment project and update the deployment framework to the current stable (5.6) version.

- Remove old deployment framework
- Update to the current stable version
- Remove old deplyoment project from your solution
- Create new deployment project
- deploy -> worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

The Deployment Framework for BizTalk targets many versions of BizTalk.  In the last few BizTalk Server releases, Microsoft has changed the SSO DLL's in every release.  As a result, the Deployment Framework includes several versions of its own SSO client DLL (SSOSettingsFileReader) to match the various BizTalk DLL versions.

When you install the Deployment Framework, it examines the currently installed version of BizTalk and installs the SSO DLL that works with that version.  If you then upgrade to another version of BizTalk, and you do not reinstall the Deployment Framework, you are out of sync.  That's why reinstalling solved your problem.

Comment: I use BizTalk 2016, updated SSO from same media (SSOClient.dll is version 10.0). I run version 5.7 of BTDF. It is asking for SSOClient version 7.0.

Is there an updated SSOSettingsFileReader somewhere to find...?

Comment: Did you install BTDF v5.7 on the machine after BizTalk 2016 was installed?  If so, the version of SSOSettingsFileReader.dll in the BTDF installation folder is the correct one for BizTalk 2016.

Comment: Yes, I believe so. BizTalk, Visual Studio, BTDF and VS tools...
Guess I will have to re-install. I hope I do not need to re-create BTDF project too...?

Comment: No, at most you'd just reinstall BTDF v5.7, no impact on your BizTalk solution.

Comment: Thomas, seems like reinstalling BTDF was enough. I made sure to open Visual Studio once after uninstalling, making sure it would protest. It did. Then installed same version again. Seems like it did the trick. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this problem before. Use ILDASM on the SSOFileReader.dll to determine exactly what version of SSOClient it is referencing. It would appear that your DEV server instance is pointed to version 9.0.1000.0, but I suspect that the BTDF DLL in QS and PROD might be different.

If that's the case, you should be able to replace the SSOFileReader.dll on the DEV machine with a copy that is referencing the earlier version of SSOClient.

Also check what version of BTDF is deployed on all machines. I know you said they appear to be the same, but if you go by the file system instead of Add/Remove Programs, both version 5.5 and 6.0 can look the same.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I don't know what happend but after I've set up the deployment project from scartch, it seems that this resolved the error. Still not sure which DLL is really referencing the SSOClient? Is it really the SSOFileReader? Before, when the error existed - I've tried to publish with various Versions of the SSOFileReader and always got the same error, referencing the same wrong SSOClient version...

So my solution was: Remove the deployment project and set it up new!